# Is there an efficient means of using ActiveRecord#Pluck for my situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, activerecord-import

I need to insert a lot of data into a new database. Like, a *lot* of data, so even nanoseconds count in the context of this query. I'm using `activerecord-import` to bulk-insert into Postgres, but that doesn't really matter for the scope of this question. Here's what I need:

I need an array that looks like this for each record in the existing DB:

```
[uuid, timestamp, value, unit, different_timestamp]
```

The issue is that the uuid is stored on the parent object that I'm looping through to get to this object, so `#pluck` works for each component aside from that. More annoying is that it is stored as an actual uuid, not a string, and needs to be stored as a uuid (not a string) in the new db as well. I'm not sure but I *think* using a `SELECT` inside of `#pluck` will return a string.

But perhaps the bigger issue is that I need to perform a conversion on the value of `value` before it is inserted again. It's a simple conversion, in effect just `value / 28` or something, but I'm finding it hard to work that into `#pluck` without also tacking on `#each_with_object` or something (which slows this down considerably)

Here's the query as it is right now. It seems really silly to me to load the entire record based on the blockage outlined above. I hope there's an alternative.

```
Klass.find_each do |klass|
    Data.where(token: klass.token).find_each do |data|
      data << [
        klass.uuid,
        data.added_at,
        data.value / conversion,
        data.unit, 
        data.created_at
      ]
    end
end
```

And no, the parent and `Data` are not associated right now and it's not an option, so I can't eager-load or just call `Klass.data` (they will be linked after this transition).

So ideally this is what I'm looking for:

```
Data.where(token: klass.token).pluck(:added_at, :value, :unit, :created_at)
```

But with the parameters outlined above.

Comment: Can't you bypass AR completely and say `insert into target_table (...) select ...`? You can include literals, calculations, joins, ... in the `select`. If you're importing data then maybe import into a temp table and then do the merging inside the database. If you're dealing with lots of data and trying to speed things up then an ORM is the last thing you want involved, you want to push the logic into the database.

Comment: @muistooshort sadly I have to use activerecord at some level in this rake task because we're pulling information from various objects, some associated and some not, which have to maintain those associations (or form new ones), and the conversion I need to do is variable and dependent on the data type. To be fair though, the bottleneck here isn't the INSERT statement, which is handled by the `activerecord-import` gem in a reasonably efficient manner. The bottleneck is the fact that we need to load the objects into memory rather than just the columns we care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you can combine a SQL `JOIN` with `pluck`:

```
Klass
  .joins('INNER JOIN datas ON datas.token = klasses.token')
  .pluck('klasses.uuid', 'datas.added_at', "datas.value / #{conversion.to_f}", 'datas.unit', 'datas.created_at')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly, this won't do it for me as the conversion is dependent on the unit for each datapoint, which can be different, so we need to determine the value of `conversion` on the fly. Another big issue with using a `join` is that I'm operating over billions of rows of data, and loading this much stuff into memory at once is a no-go.

Comment: But a JOIN won't load billions of rows of data into memory; databases are actually pretty good at managing large amounts of data, that's what they do. As far as "determining the value of `conversion` on the fly" goes, you can probably express that logic in SQL.

Comment: Ok, after figuring out how to handle the conversions this seems to be the best approach. I'll mark this as solved. Thanks for the help.